# I want to add custom ground material on my website using Meshphongmaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, unity-webgl, threejs-editor

```
    var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff43fee, specular: 0x360000 ,} );
    groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), groundMaterial );
    groundMesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add( groundMesh );
```

I want to add grass texture down but not getting any possible solution this code is taken from https://github.com/schteppe/gpu-physics.js this following github repo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture) and send it as [map property in the MechPhongMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=phong#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.map) constructor

Comment: Can you code it because I am constantly getting errors

Comment: Just want to know what has possibly wrong with my code because whenever I define a texture and add it the whole webpage just goes blank.